# I can't find what is wrong with the case statement in sql server. Can someone help me?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, operator-keyword

i want to input in the code that if the operators work load is above a certain number of minutes per week (480,420,540) then cease the operation. it is giving me an underline on the first case and i can't understand why. thanks!

```
create table HOURS (
   IDHOUR               nvarchar(2)           not null,
   STARTHOUR            time             not null,
   ENDHOUR              time             not null,
   constraint PK_HOURS primary key (IDHOUR)
)
GO
create table OPERATOR (
   IDOPERATOR          nvarchar(3)           not null,
   TYPE             nvarchar(20)           null,
   constraint TYPE
   check (TYPE in ('assistant1','assistant2','assistant3')),  
   constraint PK_OPERATOR primary key (IDOPERATOR)
)
go

insert into HOURS (idhour,starthour, endhour) values (14,'14:30','15:30');
insert into HOURS (idhour,starthour, endhour) values (1,'09:00','09:45');

insert into OPERATOR (IDOPERATOR , type) values (1,'assistant1');
 insert into OPERATOR (IDOPERATOR , type) values (2,'assistant2');
 insert into OPERATOR (IDOPERATOR , type) values (3,'asssistant3');

select * from OPERATOR 
 case 
    when TYPE = 'assistant1'
    when
             select sum(datediff(minute,starthour,endhour)) as minutes from hours > 480 then 'cease operation'
     when 
        TYPE = 'assistant2'
             select sum(datediff(minute,starthour,endhour))  as minutes from hours> 420 then 'cease operation'
     when
        TYPE = 'asssistant3'
             select sum(datediff(minute,starthour,endhour))  as minutes from hours> 540 then 'cease operation'
else 'without effect'
end
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: Your `CASE` expression is free floating mid air. That's not allowed. `CASE` cannot be used for flow control in SQL Server if you intended that. From what you wrote it's hard to guess what you really want therefore I suggest you [edit] the question and add a [example].

Comment: hello. so a user inserts hour blocks for a certain asssistant. however if that assistant keeps acumulating hours (in this case i converted to minutes) and once it passes a certain number of minutes it gives the alarm to cease operation. so it cannot keep operating after that number of minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The `HOURS` table seems to require a foreign key that references the `OPERATOR` table.

Then you can use the `CASE` in the `SELECT`.

For example.

**Sample data:**

> ```
> create table OPERATOR (
>    IDOPERATOR int not null,
>    [TYPE]     nvarchar(20) not null,
>    constraint [TYPE]
>      check ([TYPE] in ('assistant1','assistant2','assistant3')),  
>    constraint PK_OPERATOR 
>      primary key (IDOPERATOR)
> );
>
> create table HOURS (
>    IDHOUR     int identity(1,1) not null,
>    IDOPERATOR int not null,
>    STARTHOUR  time not null,
>    ENDHOUR    time not null,
>    constraint PK_HOURS 
>      primary key (IDHOUR),
>    constraint FK_HOURS_OPERATOR
>      foreign key (IDOPERATOR) references OPERATOR(IDOPERATOR)
> );
>
> insert into OPERATOR 
> (IDOPERATOR , [TYPE]) values
>   (1,'assistant1')
> , (2,'assistant2')
> , (3,'assistant3')
> ;
> insert into HOURS (idoperator, starthour, endhour) values
>   (2,'14:30','15:30')
> , (1,'09:00','17:33')
> ;
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> SELECT op.IDOPERATOR, op.[type]
> ,sum(datediff(minute,starthour,endhour)) as tmdiff
> ,case 
>  when [type] = 'assistant1'
>   and sum(datediff(minute,starthour,endhour)) > 480 
>   then 'cease operation'
>  when [type] = 'assistant2'
>   and sum(datediff(minute,starthour,endhour)) > 420 
>   then 'cease operation'
>  when [type] = 'assistant3'
>   and sum(datediff(minute,starthour,endhour)) > 540 
>  then 'cease operation'
>  when max(hr.IDOPERATOR) is null
>  then 'unknown'
>  else 'without effect'
>  end AS [result]
> FROM OPERATOR op
> LEFT JOIN HOURS hr
>   ON hr.IDOPERATOR = op.IDOPERATOR
> GROUP BY op.IDOPERATOR, op.[type];
> ```

**Results:**

> ```
> IDOPERATOR | type       | tmdiff | result         
> ---------: | :--------- | -----: | :--------------
>          1 | assistant1 |    513 | cease operation
>          2 | assistant2 |     60 | without effect 
>          3 | assistant3 |   null | unknown
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cb0286cb61821982f730e641759149eb)*

**Extra**

Not really needed for just one query. 
But a [UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine) (User Defined Function) is sometimes used if certain logic can be re-used.

> ```
> IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.ufnEvalHourDiff', N'FN') IS NOT NULL  
>     DROP FUNCTION dbo.ufnEvalHourDiff;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- A User Defined Function
> --
> CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnEvalHourDiff
> (
>  @OperatorType NVARCHAR(20), 
>  @TimeDiffMinutes INT
> )  
> RETURNS VARCHAR(30)   
> AS   
> BEGIN
>   DECLARE @result VARCHAR(30);
>
>   IF (@OperatorType = 'assistant1' 
>       AND @TimeDiffMinutes > 480) OR
>      (@OperatorType = 'assistant2' 
>       AND @TimeDiffMinutes > 420) OR
>      (@OperatorType = 'assistant3' 
>       AND @TimeDiffMinutes > 540)
>   begin
>     SET @result = 'cease operation';
>   end
>   ELSE
>     SET @result = 'without effect';
>
>   RETURN @result;
> END;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT op.IDOPERATOR, op.[type]
> , SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, starthour, endhour)) AS tmdiff
> , dbo.ufnEvalHourDiff(op.[type], SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, starthour, endhour))) as result
> FROM OPERATOR op
> LEFT JOIN HOURS hr
>   ON hr.IDOPERATOR = op.IDOPERATOR
> GROUP BY op.IDOPERATOR, op.[type];
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> IDOPERATOR | type       | tmdiff | result         
> ---------: | :--------- | -----: | :--------------
>          1 | assistant1 |    513 | cease operation
>          2 | assistant2 |     60 | without effect 
>          3 | assistant3 |   null | without effect
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8167a80e100c72739dad19c0ab76c069)*

Comment: wow thank you for telling me where the error was like this!! really appreciate it

Comment: i don't wanna be a nag but how can i transform this "case" into an "if'" statement?

Comment: You mean outside a query using T-SQL procedural language by using variables and using an [IF...ELSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql).  You can set a variable from a query. F.e. `DECLARE @x INT; select top1 @X = x from table1 where y=42;  IF @X=1 BEGIN ... END`

Comment: exactly. i used to work with Matlab and i found out that "case" can't be used as a control-of-flow process in SQL...i want the process to stop if the values overpass those limits look like i can only do this with "if" statement.I am going to try thank you a lot LukStorms!!

Comment: Well, I don't know mathlab. About the control-of-flow stuff in T-SQL, look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/control-of-flow). But  the math related functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/mathematical-functions-transact-sql) won't be as extensive as in mathlab ;)

Comment: Hi LukStorm. Can you give me an example of the "if statement"  on the same query that you gave me or is it too much to ask? i have to change again from case to "if" on other queries because i didn't know this :( Thank you a lot anyway!

Comment: Thank you a lot really Lukestorm. Can i use break after Begin to break the operation and not allow any values above those limits? because like the way it is it only telling me as an answer "cease the operation" but it isn't actually ceasing it since i can keep inputting values?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand what you really want. T-Sql also has [BREAK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/break-transact-sql).  But this is turning into an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/392334) somehow.   Maybe try things and post another more specific question.  Lots of people on SO willing to spend their free time on programming puzzles as a hobby.

Comment: Ok. But thank you a lot anyway for helping me! i will try. People are so helpful in this forum i am impressed.

Comment: @rafamaniac  Btw, if you just want to limit the query to the 'cease operation', then you could add a `HAVING` clause to the query, after the GROUP BY. F.e. `... HAVING (op.IDOPERATOR = 'assistant1' AND SUM(datediff(minute,starthour,endhour)) > 480 
   > 480) OR (op.IDOPERATOR = 'assistant2' 
      AND SUM(datediff(minute,starthour,endhour)) > 480 
   > 420) OR (op.IDOPERATOR = 'assistant3' 
      AND SUM(datediff(minute,starthour,endhour)) > 480 
   > 540)`.  But that looks ugly, so I would just use a sub-query that calculates a timediff field, then use a `WHERE` in the outer query.

Comment: Now that i am thinking since i will need to use triggers in my query so i believe the "having" part won't be necessary. is this "Thought " correct?

Answer (score 0):

If the IDhour is the same as the IDoperator, you can do something like this:

```
select b.IDoperator,b.Type,
 case when TYPE = 'assistant1' and sum(datediff(minute,b.starthour,b.endhour)) > 480 then 'cease operation'
      when TYPE = 'assistant2' and sum(datediff(minute,b.starthour,b.endhour))> 420 then 'cease operation'
      when TYPE = 'assistant2' and sum(datediff(minute,b.starthour,b.endhour))> 540 then 'cease operation'
      else 'without effect' end as flag_check
from HOURS a inner join Operator b on a.idhour=b.idoperator
Group by b.IDOperator,b.Type
```

Comment: wow thank you for telling me where the error was like this!! really appreciate it